# Font Awesome unexpected bottom margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Ok I've got headache at this point and this thing irritates me. (Hours wasted for this)

For some reason, font awesome icon has bottom margin while bootstrap's glyph seems fine.

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/damjd2sj/

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disabledTextInput">Disabled input</label>
                <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disabledSelect">Disabled select menu</label>
                <select id="disabledSelect" class="form-control">
                    <option>Disabled select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess2">Input with success</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span id="inputSuccess2Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess2">Input with success</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
                <span class="fa fa-camera-retro form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span id="inputSuccess2Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Can't check this
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set line-height for the form input

```
.form-control-feedback.fa {
 color: #3c763d;
 line-height: 34px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a4u0v3Lt/1)

The problem was that the .fa `line-height: 1` was overriding default .form-control-feedback `line-height: 34px`

Comment: well, this wasn't on the documentation, was it? :-/

Comment: It's because of the line-height being overridden by .fa class. I will explain you more in the answer. Give me some time.

Comment: ok i understand, this definitely wasn't my fault. should I file an issue on their github or something?

Comment: As it's just affecting the font awesome, i think it could be better : .form-control-feedback.fa{
    line-height:34px;
}     http://jsfiddle.net/3qkvbvc5/

Comment: Yes, that's better Yenne!